# Movie Clips when i go to 2nd frame continue from where they was at 1st frame,and not at the positions i put it

Tags: actionscript-3

I have 2 layers at frame 1,(actions and movie clips),at the movie clips layer i have 2 movie clips,A and B.
B .x = 100 and is moving to A which x = 0.
When the B hit A go to frame 2.
At frame 2 i have the same things(i copy and paste the frames).
So, the problem is when the B hit the A, i jump to 2nd frame but the B continue from x=0 and not from 100.
If i cut the B and copy it to a new layer its working normal.It start from x=100.
So,must i create new layer every frame?

Answer (score 0):

> So, the problem is when the B hit the A, i jump to 2nd frame but the B
>   continue from x=0 and not from 100... Must I create new layer every frame?

No you can just code a new position for **B** when you go to frame 2.

```
if (mcB hits mcA)
{
    gotoAndStop(2); //# go to frame 2
    mcA.x = 200; //# set new position for A
    mcB.x = 100; //# set new position for B
}
```

**A quick tip :** Your problem could be solved by having two layers like this :

- Layer 1 is actions (code)
- Layer 2 is Container (MovieClip same size as stage area)

Cut & paste all non-code frames into the container, let's call it instance name **ContMC**. Now all your code is on frame 1 only and all controlled content (MCs etc) are also within **ContMC** which is also on frame 1 only. No need for extra frames copying. Also there will be only total 2 frames because you have 2 layers. Use **ContMC** like a Stage (without moving actual Stage). So now you want to show frame 2 with different background? Use `ContMC.gotoAndStop(2);`, or you want to re-position **mcB** then use `ContMC.mcB.x = 150;`